# numeric column/field received through API call always gets saved as 0 to designer workflow variable

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, designer-workflow, workflow-variable

When I retrieve an O365 site's list's items in the designer workflow (2013) using rest api call, the Number type columns always get set to local integer variables as zeros. I have inspected the returned JSON using the Postman and Advance REST Client tools and there are non-zero values being returned, but when I copy the values to local integer variables and try to log those local variables then all I see are zeros in the workflow history list. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: try to change the local variable type from Number to string and then check. May be some format issue.

Comment: I did that and it fails validation when checking for errors. It wont accept "Number" type even. Only "Integer" works.

Comment: U sure its a Number column which you are returning . Can you add other number columns and check if all returning same 0 value in local variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what happened, but I had to delete the "**Get an item from a dictionary**" action items and re-insert new ones and that fixed the problem. 
Buggy SP Designer wasted my two days :(

This is what the path for the dictionary item looked like in that action item:
([%Variable:index%])/MyNumricListColumn
All this time I made sure that the local variable [%Variable:index%] was in fact a correct field data (judging from the way it responded to mouse clicks) and not just any plain text.

I hope this will be a lesson for others too. When in doubt, remove the action item and add it back in, no matter how correct it looks.